# Azure Synapse Copy Data/Web activity returning gibberish

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a pipeline which performs a GET call to

https://covid19.who.int/who-data/vaccination-data.csv

and save the csv file in a Synapse datalake. Other URLs are saved correctly but I cannot seem to get this URL to work. If you copy paste the URL into a browser, the CSV is downloaded perfectly fine.

I tried debugging using a Web activity, the GET call returns gibberish response.

It feels like a network problem, meaning that the GET call cannot route correctly, or something along those lines. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For reference of others , I think you are seeing this [image]

As called out in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#type-properties) webactivity always expects JSON in response and in this case the response in definietely not JSON . Moreover web activity has an upper limit of 4MB as response . Just wondering when yuu say that the web activity is working for few , I am curiuos how .

Comment: Yeah use a Copy activity with a web source, not the Web activity.